# TypeError: undefined is not a function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In my Group model, I'm exporting one function that pass the result of a query using a callback.

In my router file, I'm calling this function, after properly requiring the other file.

That's my `./models/groups.js`:

```
var groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

[...]

module.exports.getAll =  function(cb) {
    groupSchema.find({}, function(err, groups) {
        if (err) return cb(err)
        cb(null, groups)
    })
}

[...]

module.exports = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);
```

and that's my `./routes/groups.js` file.

```
var Group = require('../models/group')
router.route('/groups')

    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        Group.getAll( function(err, group){
            if (err) res.send(err)
            res.send(group)
        })
    })

[...]
```

This is not working, because every time I make a get request, I'm getting a `TypeError: undefined is not a function` error. I know I can make the query right on my router file, but I think separating things between routes and methods would be a better practice.

Comment: Have you loaded the router module in your groups js file?

Comment: You re probably overriding getAll function when you export the entire groupSchema. Try exporting getAll function after groupSchema export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the object where you defined the `getAll` function when you assign a new value to `module.exports`.

You've got 2 options:

1. Extend the model with the `getAll` function, and export as you do today.
   This basically looks like:

   ```
   var model = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);
   model.getAll = function(cb) {
     ...
   };
   module.exports = model;
   ```

   But that's not very "clean".
2. Export the model under a named property alongside the `getAll` function.
   This basically looks like this:

   ```
   module.exports.getAll = function(cb) {
     ...
   };
   module.exports.model = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);
   ```

   Then in your routes, you'd have:

   ```
   var Groups = require('../models/group');
   // Now you have Groups.getAll & Groups.model
   ```

   This is more flexible overall and will allow you to export other types/functions/values as you see fit.